# convert easticsearch query to single line format curl command for regexp

Tags: elasticsearch, hadoop, hive

I have an elasticsearch query which looks like:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "regexp":{
            "userName": ".+"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to convert it into a single line query format: something which i can use with ?q= in the URL.
What should it be?
Why i am doing this? : I want to load data from elasticsearch on Hive. Because the data is huge i want to only load queried data. is there any way i can incorporate the above query into hive table properties in the field es.query or something.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[`URI Search`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html#search-api-query-params-q) adheres to the Lucene query string [regex syntax](http://help.oncrawl.com/en/articles/1685982-lucene-regex-cheat-sheet).

With that being said, you can [use regexes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_regular_expressions) in the query strings if you wrap them in forward slashes:

```
GET index_name/_search?q=userName:/.{1,}/
```

`.+` for some reason does not work.

---

Caveat from the documentation:

> The allow_leading_wildcard parameter does not have any control over
>   regular expressions. A query string such as the following would force
>   Elasticsearch to visit every term in the index:
>
> /.*n/
>
> Use with caution!

Comment: i got it working. Thanks for the answer though, but it is not producing the same result as expected.

Comment: es.query property in hive supports dsl queries as well. So i used the dsl query as it is in the table properties.